# Using a Custom SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I setup identity as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(
    c =>
    {
        c.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        c.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        c.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        c.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
        c.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    })
    .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>()
    .AddUserValidator<CustomUserValidator>()
    .AddCustomStores<PrimaryContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I'd like to use a custom sign-in manager, but there is no `AddSignInManager` method. I have seen others suggest I add the following line below the fragment above:

```
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<IdentityUser>, CustomSignInManager>();
```

However, this causes an internal server error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyProject.Identity.CustomSignInManager' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Controllers.AccountController'.
```

How can I get my custom sign-in manager working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a misunderstanding on my part. Rather than the following in my controller:

```
public AccountController(CustomUserManager userManager,
    CustomSignInManager signInManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
}
```

This more verbose block of code appears to work in combination with the additional line shown in my original question:

```
public AccountController(CustomUserManager userManager,
    SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
{
    if(!(signInManager is CustomSignInManager))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "signInManager must be an instance of CustomSignInManager");
    }

    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager as CustomSignInManager;
}
```

This isn't especially nice but it works.

Comment: You should be using `services.AddScoped<SignInManager<MyUser>, CustomSignInManager>()` in the ConfigureServices method of your startup.cs.

Comment: @frostymarvelous I am, it didn't resolve the problem. It's mentioned in my original question and in my answer.

Comment: I didn't notice the parameter types. I'm adding an answer explaining the problem even though you've solved it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I do this in my controller constructor my custom `SignInManager` methods don't hit, the base methods are getting hit instead, so the my custom `SignInManager` is practically useless.

Comment: @nickornotto I wish I could help you mate, but this question is so old I wouldn't know where to start :(. Things have probably moved on quite a bit since I posted this.

Comment: Resolved, yourt code works. I was just overriding wrong SignInManager method, that's why my extension didn't hit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517170/how-to-extend-correctly-signinmanager?noredirect=1#comment91978754_52517170

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you should be using `services.AddScoped<SignInManager<IdentityUser>, CustomSignInManager>();`

Even if signinmanagers can be changed in controllers it would be considered as an anti-pattern as it will need to be implemented in each possible controller where you will perform a signin.

The reason to use `AddScoped` is that it will replace the default implementation, which is what most people want to do.