# How to extend correctly SignInManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to extend my `SignInManager` to override `PasswordSignInAsync`.

When trying to user it I'm getting the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'A.Extensions.ApplicationSignInManager' while attempting to activate 'A.Controllers.AccountController'.

This is my extension:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor authenticationManager,
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger) :
        base(userManager, authenticationManager, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger)
    { }

    public override Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        ...

        return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, shouldLockout);
    }
}
```

To the `ConfiguredServices` in `Startup` I added:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    //.AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager> // this causes an error: 'IdentityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddSignInManager'
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

and am injecting it into my `AccountController`:

```
public AccountController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    ApplicationSignInManager applicationSignInManager
    )
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _applicationSignInManager = applicationSignInManager;
}
```

What did I miss or how to include my custom `SignInManager` in the startup?

Comment: You haven not registered `ApplicationSignInManager` with the DI container.

Comment: `AddSignInManager` does not exist in ASP.NET Core 1.0 - You should strongly consider upgrading to 2.1 if possible.

Comment: @Nkosi, please let me know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: @Kirk do you mean there is no way extending `SignInManager` in .NET Core 1?

Comment: @nickornotto I agree with the suggestion to upgrade to more recent version. If unable to upgrade, you can write the code your self using the source from the more recent version, which is available on Github https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Identity/IdentityBuilderExtensions.cs#L46

Comment: @Kirk I applied the duplicate and it removes the problem with `ApplicationSignInManager` injection but it doe snot work as expected. When I call `var passwordSignInResult = await _applicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);` within my login it does not hit the custom `PasswordSignInAsync`, it hits the `base.PasswordSignInAsync` so is practically useless

Comment: How do you know it's not hitting your custom class here? Is it a breakpoint that's not being hit? I'd remove all references to `_applicationSignInManager` and just use `_signInManager` without any of that casting, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the breakpoint not hitting @Kirk

Comment: @nickornotto why are two signin managers being injected into the controller?

Comment: Because I;m using the original one in other part of the code. And removing it doesn't change anything - if I have only the custom one, the custom `PasswordSignInAsync` still is not getting hit.

Comment: @nickornotto there are multiple overloads of that method. You most likely override the one that is not being called. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#L273

Comment: And that's the correct answer! Thanks @Nkosi